# typecast the return value of a function to an unrelated type of the same size

Tags: c++

Suppose type A and type B are of the same size, i.e. `sizeof(A) == sizeof(B)`, How can I re-interpret some memory containing B as A?

What I want to do is:

```
B myFunction()
{
     A  x;

     // do some operations here.

     // Solution 1: not working, since there is no such conversion function called 'B'.
     //    return  B(x);

     // Solution 2:
     return  *(B*)(&x);       // should work.
}
```

It seems that Solution 2 is working.  However, if the entity to be returned is not a variable like `x` above, but a function...  Say, I have a function `f2()` as below:

```
A f2()
{
   ....
}
```

in `myFunction()`, I want the return statement to use `f2()`:

```
     return  *(B*)(& (f2()));    // definitely not working.
```

i.e. to interpret the return value of f2() as type B.

It is apparent that the return value of a function does not have an address, and thus can not take the address operator `&`.

Then, how can I do that?

Comment: Can you be dissuaded from doing this an rethink your design? Because there is a way, but I'd rather not encourage this approach.

Comment: Ya.  I admit that the design has some problem.  The reason is that two engineers design two different classes of the same functionality, and used it in their different codes. When it's time to merge.. you know..  Very hard to unify them in a short time to meet project deadline.

Comment: Perhaps I just use a variable of type A to take the return value. and then force conversion to B.  Hopefully the compiler will optimize out the variable.

Comment: Well, there is always the good old fundamental theorem of software engineering. Add a level of indirection. It's usually better than a cast.

Answer (score 3):

> It seems that Solution 2 is working

Depending on the types A and B, it probably violates strict aliasing rules. This is undefined behavior, but a common result is that it works at low levels of optimization and goes wrong at high levels of optimization or with a different compiler.

Think of this as sticking a gun, with a round chambered and the safety off, into your waistband. Yeah, it hasn't gone off. Yet.

> The reason is that two engineers design two different classes of the same functionality, and used it in their different codes

I *think*, given the extra information you've provided, that if A and B are two standard-layout classes with the same data members in the same order, then you're OK. But don't quote me on that, check the standard for yourself.

In any case, the usual thing if you don't want to touch the two classes would just be to define a function to convert from one to the other:

```
B A_to_B(const A &a) {
    B b{a.thiss, a.thatt, a.the_otherr};
    return b;
}
```

Making this function a `friend` of A, if that proves necessary, shouldn't break anything. Of course, if A has private data members then your standing is pretty weak to assume that this data you're not allowed to know about not only exists, but is laid out the same way as B.

> How can I re-interpret some memory containing A as B?

```
A x = f2();
B result;
std::memcpy(&result, &x, sizeof result);
return result;
```

This code avoids violating strict aliasing rules, but still *might* cause undefined behavior, if there exist trap representations of the type B in your implementation. But that's unavoidable: you can't do type-punning by any means if the value you start with isn't a valid bit-pattern of the type you want to read it as. Also if the type B has non-trivial constructor(s) and/or destructor then you're asking for trouble, and there may be no way around this other than to allow B's proper lifecycle to happen.

Comment: Can't we use simply `reinterpret_cast<B>(a)`

Comment: @Zereges: depends on the types, but in this case `B(a)` doesn't compile. That's a synonym for the C-style cast `(B)a`, which is already capable of doing a `reinterpret_cast` where permitted.

Answer (score 1):

A more detailed answer on using union:
You can attempt to unite a and b:

```
union AB
{
    A a;
    B b;
};
```

And when you use both functions, use AB:

```
A f2()
{
   ....
}

B myFunction()
{
     AB  x;
     x.a = f2();
     return  x.b;
}
```

Comment: I'd check your syntax. The union you posted isn't a valid definition.

Comment: @StoryTeller Maybe, can you point it out? It will help! Thanks!

Comment: @StoryTeller Yeah you are correct, i treated it as an enum. Will fix!

Answer (score 0):

God thats ugly... but OK (I hope the question is just academical and not really a part of any real code)

```
A a;
B b;
memcpy(&b,&a,sizeof(B))
```

If you use pointers it's easier but because you return by value you need the memory first. And you cannot use any assignment because that would use a copy/assignment constructor and that may mess up things inside the classes (which of the both copy constructors woul be used etc)